# AUTO_INCREMENT-Value wrong after reboot of memsql

Tags: auto-increment, singlestore

After rebooting a server with memsql the auto_increment value is lower than the maximum used id, so I can't insert more data in the table.

So currently the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  ProductID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
  PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=3332
```

select max(ProductID) from Product;
+----------------+
| max(ProductID) |
+----------------+
|       72766784 |
+----------------+

How can I repair this table?

Answer (score 0):

try running this on the aggregator giving you errors:

```
aggregator sync auto_increment
```

Inserting values directly into auto_increment columns is not well supported in MemSQL right now.  You need to manually run the command above to set the new "next auto_increment value" after you do an explicit insert